# Calculating power raised to a number

Tags: c

I am calculating the power of `x` raised to `n`. I can't understand one thing: why is it showing segmentation fault when I am both declaring and initializing the temp variable at the start? I do know what segmentation fault is, but why is it showing.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int power(int x,unsigned int y)
{
int temp=power(x,y/2);
if(y==0)
    return 1;
if(y%2==0)
    return temp*temp;
else 
    return x*temp*temp;
}

//Driver function
int main(int u, int v)
{
printf("Enter the value of u and v");
scanf("%d %u",&u,&v);
printf("%d",power(u,v));

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You never get as far as `if(y==0)`, so you keep calling `power(x, 0)` until you run our of stack.

Comment: `int power(int x,unsigned int y)
{
int temp=power(x,y/2);`
is resulting in infinite recursion.

Comment: That is an unusual definition for the `main` function. It's usually something like `int main(int argc, char** argv)`. Are you sure your implementation allows such a definition of `main` (though probably not the cause of your segv which is more likely a recursion stack overflow as described in the comments above)?

Comment: Also, `int v;` should be `unsigned int v;`

Comment: @bandara.Why is it running out of stack?Sorry but I can't understand that because I haven't assigned y to 0.Can you explain please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will recurse infinitely.  You need a small adjustment [please pardon the gratuitous style cleanup]:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
power(int x, unsigned int y)
{
    //int temp = power(x, y / 2);

    if (y == 0)
        return 1;

    int temp = power(x, y / 2);

    if (y % 2 == 0)
        return temp * temp;
    else
        return x * temp * temp;
}

// Driver function
int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    int u;
    unsigned int v;

    printf("Enter the value of u and v");
    scanf("%d %u", &u, &v);

    printf("%d\n", power(u, v));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also, `int v;` should be `unsigned int v;`

Comment: @CoolGuy Yes. I cleaned up the u/v as `main` arguments, but kept OP's original type. Fixed.